# Multiple File Upload Using Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I already program ajax multiple file upload form but it is not working properly.

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" id="postfrom" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" multiple 
           accept=".mp4, .mov, .m4v, .MPEG-4, .gif, .jpg, .png"/>
</form>

<button type="button" class="btnb btnb-primary" id="submitpost"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitpost", function(){
    $("#postfrom").submit();
});


$("#postfrom").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         url : "/php/post_submit.php",
         type: "POST",
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         data : new FormData(this),
         success: function(response){
            $('.result').html(response);
            alert(response);

         },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES);

?>
```

How to solve this error. I get nothing from PHP response. I only get `Array()` response only.

Comment: you can not do this with new FormData(this),. You need to create one object of FormData. And runa for loop with file Control's ID and append each file into that  object. Then pass that object on ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just ensure that your URL is pointing in the right URL address on your server you can see the log on your network tab.

You can also try the complete URL path `http://` if your in the same domain.

[image]

Comment: What is your console and network behavior on browsers DevTool displaying?

Comment: yeah it is right URL that is why i get array() response